# Update selected rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like below

```
    name    spent
    a       3.2
    a       5.5
    a       3
    b       4.6
    b       16
    c       1.2
    c       7
```

I want to update the spent column of first 2 where name is "a"

I want to do it in one query

my desired result

```
    name    spent
    a       1
    a       1
    a       3
    b       4.6
    b       16
    c       1.2
    c       7
```

Comment: DB fiddle linki  :https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=ad1e98e37db656543e474dc4c2c3fe87

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a subquery to find the `id` values of the first 2 rows of values with name `a`, and then `UPDATE` only rows which have those `id` values:

```
UPDATE table1
SET spent = 1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id 
             FROM table1
             WHERE name = 'a'
             ORDER BY id
             LIMIT 2);
SELECT * FROM table1
```

Output:

```
id  name    spent
6   a       3
1   a       1
4   a       1
2   b       16
5   b       4.6
7   c       1.2
3   c       7
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=4f427070368cb9dde25f8a6fe62e290d)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `limit` to only update the first two rows where `name = a`:

```
update TABLE
set spent = 1
where name = a
order by id
limit 2;
```

Comment: got ERROR:  syntax error at or near "limit"
LINE 5: limit 2;

Comment: Please copy the exact code you have tried before and write it here.

Comment: @Shadiqur you have written `tablename` instead of `table1` in the `update` statement!

Answer (score 1):

why not you just consider id

```
update table
  set spent=1
where id in (1,4) and name='a'
```

as you updated question and no id in your sample data so you could use subquery

```
UPDATE table1
SET spent = 1
WHERE spent IN (SELECT spent 
             FROM table1
             WHERE name = 'a'
             ORDER BY spent
             LIMIT 2) and name='a';

select * from table1 order by name,spent;
name    spent
  a     1
  a     1
  a     3
  b     4.6
  b     16
  c     1.2
  c     7
```

Comment: my ids are not fixed i want to select top 2 name and update them

Comment: @guradio i edited answer after op updated his question

Answer (score 1):

```
update table_name set spent='1' where name='a' and id in (4,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`update tablename set spent = 1 where name = 'a' and id in  (select top 2 id from tablename where name = 'a' order by id asc)`

I would do a select a top first then from there update according to generated ID from that select

Comment: got this
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2"
LINE 4: (select top 2 id from tablename where name = 'a')

Answer (score -1):

```
update table_name set spent=1 where name='a' and spent>3
```

Comment: @MuhammadWaheed  you are wrong i also checked name = 'a' so for id 5,2,3 will not be changed.

Comment: In that table there are 3 row with name =a ;but 2 of those spent value is above 3. So the query will update those two row and set the spent column value into 1